# CSS Background Color Switch

Tags: css, css-transitions, background-color

Is it possible to switch background colors just with CSS3?

I have tried using keyframe animations but that only transitions the background color.  All I want to do is have the background color change after 5 seconds with no transition.  I do not want any hover effects etc..

I figured there surely must be a way if I can fade it in just to switch to it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Well, to make a `transition` without a `transition-duration` but with `delay`, use

```
html { background: red; transition: background 0s 5s; }
```

But the problem here is, that there is no state change, so the transition won't work. I think you would need some JavaScript. Something like this:

```
$('html').addClass('loaded');
```

When the css is

```
html { background: red; transition: background 0s 5s; }
html.loaded { background: blue; }
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dUBzq/)

Side note: Be aware of [vendor prefixes](http://peter.sh/experiments/vendor-prefixed-css-property-overview/) for the `transition` statements.

### Using `animations`

This will not need JavaScript:

```
html {
    background: blue; /* fallback */
    animation: switchColor 5s;
}

@keyframes switchColor {
    0% {
        background: red;
    }
    99.9999% {
        background: red;
    }
    100% {
        background: blue;
    }
}
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dGmtq/)

### Using pure jQuery

Or you might use just JavaScript for this. If you only want to switch the color with no transition, use the `setTimeout()` function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('html').css('background', 'blue');
}, 5000);
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hnWg9/)